# Loop of pushes in navigation view Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am using `storyboards`. 
Here is my views

```
My NavigationController --> [Series of ViewControllers] ->About View Controller
```

Now from `AboutViewController` I have

```
AboutViewController--> ViewController1-->ViewController2-->ViewController3-->ViewController4-->
```

back to `AboutViewController using PUSH SEGUE`.

Now suppose I am a user and i do above and after coming back to `AboutViewController` I again go to `viewController1` and so on upto `viewController4` and does this loop a number of times.

I want to know if this will cause some memory issues since views are put on stack on `navigationController`. If so What strategy should be used to come back to `aboutViewController` from `ViewController4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't create any memory issues. iOS takes care it for you. When it present's another view, previous view gets deallocated automatically if you don't have strong reference cycle(always have weak reference to the parent in child viewcontroller). You can try adding initWithCoder and dealloc methods like below in each view controllers and see what happens.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        NSLog(@"init ViewController");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc ViewController");
}
```

Also add viewDidAppear - ViewDidDisappear methods to see exactly what's happening. It's really interesting. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

P.S see [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) tutorials for details.